# paper-dialog in polymer does not open when called from within an event listener

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x, custom-events, paper-dialog

I having trouble opening a paper-dialog when this is called via a dispatchEvent that is sent via another component. This triggers the overlay, but the dialog is not shown.

I have the following components setup:

- a general parent component containing 2 iron-pages with custom child-pages, and a listener for the fired event
- a first page component : this has a button firing a custom event
- a second page component : containing a function for opening dialog.

The goal is that via a dispatched event, from first child page component, this is captured by the parent component, and a method is called on the second page component, opening a paper-dialog.
This works fine when the event is fired and captured on the same component, but not when different components are in play...
The paper-dialog does not open. Instead only the backdrop is activated.

Below some snippets of code (not complete to keep things compact) :

**1)The parent component, containing the 2 children & having a listener**

```
<dom-module id="parent-comp">
<template>
//....
<div class="main-frame">
  <iron-pages id="pages" selected="[[state]]" attr-for-selected="state" fallback-selection="first">
    <child-page-component id="first" state="first"></child-page-component>
    <child-page-component id="second" state="second"></child-page-component>
  </iron-pages>
/....
<template>
//....

<script>
   class ParentPage extends Polymer.Element {
      // ... all needed stuff...

      ready(){
        super.ready();
        // LISTEN FOR event 'test-dialog' !!
        this.addEventListener('test-dialog', (e) => this._onTestEvent(e));
      }

      //...

      _onTestEvent(e){
         // When event is hit, call the second child method...
         this.$.second.callTestEvent();
      }
   }
   //....
 </script>
```

2) **In the first child-component**, there is a button triggering a dispatchEvent that is captured by the parent...

```
  // ....

  <paper-button raised on-tap="_test">Test</paper-button>
  // ....
  <script>
      class ChildPageComponent extends Polymer.Element {
      //....
      _test(){
          // FIRE CUSTOM EVENT 'test-dialog'
          this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('test-dialog', {
              bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: {}
          }));
      }
     //....
```

3) **In the second child-component**, there is a dialog definition, and a function that can be called from the parent.

```
  // ....
  <paper-dialog id="dialogtst" modal>
     <div>
        <h1>hello</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="buttons">
        <paper-button dialog-confirm>Close</paper-button>
     </div>
  </paper-dialog>
  // ....

  // ....
  <script>
      class ChildPageComponent extends Polymer.Element {

      //....
      callTestEvent(){
          // Open Dialog....
          this.$.dialogtst.open();  // SHOULD OPEN RIGHT??
      }
     //....
```

But as said, the full screen is overlayed with the modal backdrop, and no dialog is shown. It all works when called via a button directly, on any of the components, or when the event is capured in the same component... But not when it is passed to the parent...

***Can someone explain why and how to get it working ?***
All advice is very much appriciated !

Comment: If you console log from each function, where does it stop? Does callTestEvent() get a called? What happens when you remove the iron pages from the parent? Also could it be that dialog is open but you can't see it because iron-page is hiding the component thats contain it?

Comment: You are both firing the event and then expecting to catch the event in the same component `ChildPageComponent`?  Your event is going to bubble upwards, won't be heard from component from which it's fired.

Comment: @codeMonkey : the event is fired in the first child, captured by the parent, who calls the second child. There is no issue of getting the event - this works fine - The only problem is that the dialog is not shown